# Add a centered source to figure captions

Tags: floats, source

Just a question. I used this code to create a source under my figures:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{%
    #1%
    \\\hspace{\linewidth}%
    \textbf{Source:} #2%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [ht]
  \centering
  \captionsource{Caption}{ref, cite or free Text}
  \label{fig:gliederung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I want my caption and source to be centered. I don't know how to manage that. Can anyone help me with that? 
Thank a lot!!!

Comment: For similar cases is intended package `copyrightbox`. The result  with its use is a bit different from that you like to obtain, but seems to be more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package with the following option.

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

See the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) for more settings.

**Edit:**
To achieve the same distance of the "caption" and "source" lines, you have to modify the `\captionsource` command e.g. like this

```
\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
    \caption[{#1}]{%
        #1%
        \\%     
        \textbf{Source:} #2%
    }%
}
```

Comment: Although it does not do so here, this will cause bad boxes in other cases because of the use of `\\` to end the line.

Answer (score 1):

While I would thoroughly recommend the **caption** package if you wish to configure captions further, you do not really need it in order to achieve the desired result in this case.

The basic problem, I think, is that `\centering` applies to *paragraphs* - not *lines*. It is only applied to the paragraph when the paragraph ends and is typeset.

As defined, however, the paragraph containing your caption does not get ended so the `\centering` is ineffective. Moreover using `\\` will cause bad boxes in many cases, when not centring text. Generally, this should only be used within specified contexts such as `tabular` and `array` environments. Inside a `center` environment, it is converted to a new paragraph, but `\centering` is not `center` and you do not want the additional vertical spacing the latter would add here.

But the fix is straightforward as there is no reason you cannot include paragraph breaks into your macro definition.

```
\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{#1}\par
  \textbf{Source:} #2\par}
```

will produce

[image: centred caption and source]

If you want some extra space between the caption and source, the best solution is probably to add some *skip*. For example,

```
  \caption[{#1}]{#1}\smallskip\par
```

produces

[image: more space]

`\medskip` or `\bigskip` will add correspondingly larger amounts of space compared with `\smallskip`.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\captionsource}[2]{%
  \caption[{#1}]{#1}\smallskip\par
  \textbf{Source:} #2\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [ht]
  \centering
  \captionsource{Caption}{ref, cite or free Text}
  \label{fig:gliederung}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```